# Promises not forcing sequential execution

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, promise

I'm attempting to write a program that loads an image into a canvas and then reads the image data from it after it loads. Here are the two functions that do the different operations.

This function reads the next image in the file input array

```
function readNextImage(i) {
d = new $.Deferred();
if (fileUpload.files && fileUpload.files[i]) {
var FR = new FileReader();
FR.onload = function(e) {
  fabric.Image.fromURL(e.target.result, function(img) {
    img.set({
      left: 0,
      top: 0,
      evented: false
    });
    img.scaleToWidth(canvas.width);
    img.setCoords();
    canvas.add(img);
  })
};
FR.readAsDataURL(fileUpload.files[i]);
}
d.resolve();
return d.promise();
}
```

This one actually parses through the image data to extract information from it

```
function read_image () {
d = new $.Deferred();
imgData = context.getImageData(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
data = imgData.data;
var value_min=100;
var value_max=0;
var total_light=0;
var total_shadow=0;
for (var j=0; j<boundary.length; j+=1) {
        var hsv = rgb2hsv(data[boundary[j]], data[boundary[j]+1], data[boundary[j]+2]);
        if(hsv.v < value_min){
            value_min = hsv.v;
        }
        if(hsv.v > value_max){
            value_max = hsv.v;
        }
}

var value_median = (value_min + value_max)/2;

for (var j=0; j<boundary.length; j+=1) {
    var hsv = rgb2hsv(data[boundary[j]], data[boundary[j]+1], data[boundary[j]+2]);
    if(hsv.v < value_median){
        //console.log("this value:"+hsv.v);
        total_shadow+=1;
    } else {
        total_light+=1;
    }
}       

var total_interception = total_shadow/boundary.length;
console.log("interception:" + total_interception);
total_interception = total_interception * 100;
total_interception = total_interception.toPrecision(4);
document.getElementById("interception").innerHTML=total_interception.toString()+"%";

d.resolve();
return d.promise();
}
```

and finally here is the code that calls both of the functions

```
for (var image_num=0; image_num<fileUpload.files.length; image_num+=1){
    promise = readNextImage(image_num).then(read_image);
}
```

I read about promises because it was executing asynchronously and I wanted to force it to load the image into the canvas before doing anything else. Currently the program is doing the `read_image()` function for as many times as there are image in the file input and then after it does that it then loads the canvas with the images sequentially. So right now it's only getting the data from the first image loaded.

Comment: `read_image` is synchronous, it should not return a promise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `ReadNextImage()` you're resolving the promise immediately before returning it, which essentially turns it back into a plain old synchronous function: the promise resolves without waiting for anything.

Instead resolve the promise inside the `FR.onload` callback; that way it will wait until after the image data has loaded before triggering the promise's `then()`.

The `readImage()` function doesn't appear to need to be asynchronous at all; you can simply remove the promise-related code from that function.

Also -- I'm not entirely clear on the context here or what you're doing with the canvas code, but I suspect that rather than having both functions draw to and read from what appears to be the same canvas, which is going to cause collisions when there's more than one file in the loop, you probably want to have the first function retrieve its data asynchronously and then pass it explicitly to the second synchronous function:

```
function readNextImage(i) {
  d = new $.Deferred();
  if (fileUpload.files && fileUpload.files[i]) {
    var FR = new FileReader();
    FR.onload = function(e) {
      // ... etc to build up the `img` var...
      d.resolve(img); // <-- here, and pass the data along
    };
    FR.readAsDataURL(fileUpload.files[i]);
  }
  // d.resolve() <-- not here
  return d.promise();
}

function read_image(imgData) {
  // Do stuff™ to `imgData` (synchronously) from the param, rather than reading from the canvas
}

for (var image_num=0; image_num<fileUpload.files.length; image_num+=1){
  readNextImage(image_num).then(read_image);
}
```

Comment: Alright so that solved the problem of it reading the same image multiple times, but now it is only executing the read_image() function once

Comment: I admit to not fully understanding the image manipulation you're doing, but I've expanded the answer to show how to pass data through the resolve callback instead of depending on the current state of the `canvas`.

Comment: `jquery.js:3860 jQuery.Deferred exception: Cannot read property '280108' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined at read_image line 263` which is at this line in the code `data = imgData.data;` looks like it doesn't know how to deal with that when passing it through. any thoughts?

Comment: `img` may not be the variable you want to pass through, that's the part of your code I'm not clear on -- but the idea is that `d.resolve(foo)` will pass `foo` as the first parameter to the promise's `then()`, or in this case your read_image function.

Comment: Alright, thanks so much for your help. I'll see if I can figure it out from here!